# multiple simultaneous ajax requests with same callback but different arguments

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am developing a grid based content page (like google maps grid,you load the cell when you need it).

To do this i have a defined grid with coordinates, when a cell is to be shown, i make an ajax request to get the specific contents and insert them into the cell.

When i have multiple cells to feed in the same viewport, i have to perform multiple ajax calls, with the callback function to populate the cells.

Ideally i would pass as args the coordinates of the cell to populate

```
//Where serviceURI is the url to the endpoint
//gridState.x is the X coordinate
//gridState.y is the Y coordinate

getData(serviceURI, gridState.x, gridState.y);
```

This is my function

```
    var getData = function(url , dayId, row) {

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
             httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }catch (e) {
                try {
                      httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }catch (e) {}
            }
        }

        if (!httpRequest) {
              console.log('Could not create XMLHTTP instance');
              return false;
        }
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = (function(d,r){
            return function(){
                if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
                  if (httpRequest.status === 200) {

                    //   FUNCTION WHERE THE CELL WILL BE FILLED
                    populate(JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText), d, r);

                    return true;
                  } else {
                    console.log('There was a problem with the request.');
                      return false;
                  }
                }
            }
        })(dayId, row);
        httpRequest.open('GET', url);
        httpRequest.send();
    }
```

The problem is that, before the response of the first call arrives, other ajax requests are made and the args passed to the callback function are those of the latest calls.

How i could get the correct args to be passed on to the callback without being overwritten is a mystery to me!

If anyone has a light to shine on me, i would be very thankful!

EDITED to include the `populate()` function:

```
    var populate = function(obj, dayId, row){
        var created = createRow(row),
        channels = obj.gridtv.channels,
        dayCont = document.getElementById('day'+dayId),
        cell = dayCont.getElementsByClassName('inner-cell'),
        first = dayId===0&&row===0?true:false;

        for(c=0; c< channels.length; c++){
            if(created||first){
                var meogo;
                channels[c].meogo==="true"?meogo=' active':meogo='';
                var chNum = channels[c].number;
                chNum<10?chNum="0"+chNum:false;
                gridElements.chCont.innerHTML += '<div class="channel"><div class="channel-number" id="ch'+channels[c].id+'"> <span>'+ chNum +'</span><div class="meogo-state glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle'+meogo+'"></div></div><img class="channel-logo" src="'+channels[c].logo+'">';
            }
            var progRow = document.createElement("div");
            progRow.className = "programm-row"
            for(pr=0;pr<channels[c].programs.length;pr++){
                var start = channels[c].programs[pr].startTime;
                var end = channels[c].programs[pr].endTime;
                var classNow = '';
                var marginLeft='';

                if(pr===0){
                    marginLeft = (start.split(':')[0]*(scale*2)+((start.split(':')[1]/30)*scale))+"px";
                }

                if(start.split(':')[0]+start.split(':')[1]<=(hours*100)+minutes && end.split(':')[0]+end.split(':')[1]>=(hours*100)+minutes){
                    classNow = ' live-now';
                    progNowIds[c]={"id":channels[c].programs[pr].id, "end":end.split(':')[0]+end.split(':')[1]};
                }
                end.split(':')[0]==="00"?end="24:"+end.split(':')[1]:false;
                var size = ((end.split(':')[0]-start.split(':')[0])*scale*2)+(((end.split(':')[1]-start.split(':')[1])/30)*scale)-4;
                var progAnchor = document.createElement('a');
                progAnchor.className = "programm"+classNow;
                progAnchor.id = 'p'+channels[c].programs[pr].id;
                progAnchor.style.width = size+'px';
                progAnchor.style.marginLeft = marginLeft;
                progAnchor.href = "#";

                progAnchor.innerHTML += '<div class="prog-content"><h1 class="prog-title">'+channels[c].programs[pr].name+'</h1><div class="prog-time"> <span class="start">'+start+'</span> - <span class="end">'+end+'</span></div><div class="icons"><div class="more">+</div><div class="record'+channels[c].programs[pr].recordType+'"></div></div></div>';

                progRow.appendChild(progAnchor);
            }
            cell[row].appendChild(progRow);
        }

    }
```

> SOLVED : I was not declaring the XMLHttpRequest object, so all following instances were going over the previous!

Comment: The way you describe it, you shouldn't be having this problem. Since you're passing the values to the function as arguments, they shouldn't be getting replaced with values from future calls of that function. Please provide more code.

Comment: Can you show us what's in your `populate()` function. I fail to see an issue in your current snippet.

Comment: I edited to include the populate() function